# Returning true or false in scheme (#t & #f)

Tags: boolean, scheme

```
(define (is-non-neg num)(if (> 0 num) (* -1 1)(* 1 1)))
```

I want to replace the `(* -1 1)` and `(* 1 1)` to return #t and #f. How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you calculate `(* 1 1)`? just write `1`. Similarly, `(* -1 1)` is simply `-1`. And to return `#t` or `#f` well, then write `#t` or `#f`!

Answer (score 2):

`(> 0 num)` is asking: "is zero greater than `num`?" in other words, "is `num` negative?" and that seems to contradict the procedure's name, `is-non-neg`, which I assume means "is `num` not negative?", that is: "is `num` zero or positive?".

It's way simpler that that, in fact there's a built-in procedure that does just what (I think) you intended:

```
(define (is-non-neg num)
  (not (negative? num)))
```

For example:

```
(is-non-neg -1)
=> #f
(is-non-neg 0)
=> #t
(is-non-neg 1)
=> #t
```

Answer (score 0):

`(define (is-non-neg num)(> 0 num))`

Comment: You're confused about how the `>` comparison operator works, it's the other way around. Check my answer.